# SQL Server database level audit filtering does not work

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2014

I have `SQL Server 2014 Enterprise Edition` installed. Due to privacy considerations, SELECT statements on private data need to be logged, except for a specific domain user, used by a service which writes to the database.

Creating a database level audit specification works well. E.g.

```
CREATE DATABASE AUDIT SPECIFICATION [DatabaseAuditSpecification-01]
FOR SERVER AUDIT [My_Audit]
ADD (SELECT ON SCHEMA::[dbo] BY [public])
WITH (STATE = OFF)
GO
```

causes all SELECT statements from everyone to be written to the log file. When I replaced `SCHEMA::[dbo]` with `[MyTable]`, the log was correctly filtered for SELECTs on `MyTable` only.

But when I replaced `public` by specific user name `MYDOMAIN\myuser`, the log entries are not filtered for the given user name as I would have expected.

```
CREATE DATABASE AUDIT SPECIFICATION [DatabaseAuditSpecification-01]
FOR SERVER AUDIT [My_Audit]
ADD (SELECT ON SCHEMA::[dbo] BY [MYDOMAIN\myuser])
WITH (STATE = OFF)
GO
```

Every SELECT *issued by any user* was logged instead.

I queried `sys.server_principals` to check whether the given user was a valid principal name, but it actually showed up in the result.

What is wrong with my second audit specification?

**Edit:** It seems like if the CREATE statement in question has been **silently** discarded. When issuing *Script Database Audit Specification as ...* in SQL management studio, the original statement is written to the query editor window.
However, changing the value to others than user names (e.g., replacing `public` by `dbo`) worked well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case, `MYDOMAIN\myuser` was a *server principal*, not a *database principal*. Only the latter ones can be used in database audit definitions.

Database principals can be either database users, or roles (see [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181127.aspx)). I created a new database role to be used in the audit definition. Then I created the logins for the users in question and chose the apt role membership under *User mapping*.

**Hint:** For some reasons, it seems necessary to define the role prior to adding the logins for the users. Adding existing logins as role members did not work for me.